# read from a pipe is blocked after close writer

Tags: c, unix, ipc, system-calls

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    int childs[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        int p[2];
        if (pipe(p) == -1) { perror("pipe"); exit(1); }

        pid_t pid = fork();
        if (pid) {
            close(p[0]);
            childs[i] = p[1];
        }
        else {
            close(p[1]);
            printf("child %d start\n", i + 1);

            char buf[10];
            buf[0] = 0;
            int r;
            if ((r = read(p[0], buf, 9)) == -1) { ... }

            printf("child %d read %s (%d), finish\n", i + 1, buf, r);

            sleep(2);
            exit(0);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    //        if (argc > 1) {
    //            write(childs[i], "42", 2);
    //        }
    // ============== HERE >>>
        close(childs[i]);
    }

    pid_t pid;
    while ((pid = waitpid(-1, NULL, 0)) > 0) {
         printf("child %d exited\n", pid);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output with comment:

```
child 1 start
child 2 start
child 3 start
child 3 read  (0), finish
```

The next line is displayed after 2 seconds

```
child 2 read  (0), finish
```

The next line is displayed after 2 seconds

```
child 1 read  (0), finish
```

I do not write to the channel in the parent. Closing it, I want to give a signal to the child that will be waiting in the `read`.

It seems that there is a following. `Сhild N` expected finishes reading from the result `0`, it's ok.  Children `2 (N-1)` and `1` are locked in a `read` to a child `3` is completed. Then the child `1` is similar will wait.

Why lock occur?

Answer (score 2):

Child processes inherit open file descriptors from their parent. Your main process opens file descriptors in a loop (using `pipe`, keeping only the write ends). Child 1 inherits no descriptors (except for stdin/stdout/stderr); child 2 inherits `childs[0]` (the descriptor going to child 1); child 3 inherits `childs[0]` and `childs[1]` (the descriptors going to child 1 and 2).

`read` on a pipe blocks as long as any write descriptor is still open (because it could be used to send more data). So child 1 waits (because child 2 and child 3 still have an open write descriptor) and child 2 waits (because child 3 still has an open write descriptor); only child 3 sleeps and exits. This causes its file descriptors to close, which wakes up child 2. Then child 2 sleeps and exits, closing its file descriptors, which finally wakes up child 1.

---

If you want to avoid this behavior, you have to close the open file descriptors in each child:

```
    else {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            close(childs[j]);
        }
        close(p[1]);
        printf("child %d start\n", i + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The write ends of the pipes are getting inherited by the children.
Since filedescriptor are ref-counted, the write end is only considered closed if all references to it are closed.

Below is your code, slightly refactored, with a fix added:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    int children_w[3];

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        int p[2];

        if (0>pipe(p)) 
            { perror("pipe"); exit(1); }

        pid_t pid;
        if(0> (pid= fork()))
            { perror("fork"); exit(1); }

        if(pid==0) {
            /* Fix -- close the leaked write ends  */
            int j;
            for(j=0; j<i; j++)
                close(children_w[j]);
            /* end fix*/ 
            close(p[1]);
            printf("child %d start\n", i + 1);

            char buf[10];
            buf[0] = 0;
            int r;
            if ((r = read(p[0], buf, 9)) == -1) { perror("read");/*...*/ }

            printf("child %d read %s (%d), finish\n", i + 1, buf, r);

            sleep(2);
            exit(0);
        }
        children_w[i] = p[1];
        close(p[0]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    //        if (argc > 1) {
    //            write(childs[i], "42", 2);
    //        }
    // ============== HERE >>>
        close(children_w[i]);
    }

    pid_t pid;
    while ((pid = waitpid(-1, NULL, 0)) > 0) {
         printf("child %d exited\n", pid);
    }

    return 0;
}
```